# How do we change a home page component from narrow column to wide column after creation of the component

Tags: home-page-component

I had created a custom homepage component and set to be using the narrow column. But on customer feedback want to change to wide column.

I cant seem to find a way to change it. Is it possible. 
The simple solution was to delete the component and create it back as wide column one. I would like to believe there should be a simple way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is that you cannot change the display type after creation. This restriction is in place because the component may be used in one or more layouts, and changing it would violate those layouts' constraints. In short, this limitation is there so they could ignore the next logical question: should they remove modified components from layouts, or prevent you from changing the type if it is already on a layout?